# display incomplete orders in frontend template

Tags: expresso-store

I want to display a list of all orders that were incomplete in a frontend template for Expresso Store. I have template that shows all orders that have been processed something along the lines of :

```
{exp:store:orders limit="2000"}
    {order_id}
{/exp:store:orders}
```

In the backend I can see that I can filter by order status == Incomplete. However, when I try to do the same in the template I don't get any results. I tried

```
{exp:store:orders limit="2000" order_status="Incomplete"}
    {order_id}
{/exp:store:orders}
```

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

I'm now using the query module, it spits out the order id, but not the rest of the info I need. The code looks like this:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT order_id FROM exp_store_orders ORDER BY order_date DESC LIMIT 2000"}
                <tr>
                  <td>{order_id}</td>
                  <td>{order_date format="%j %M %Y"}</td>
                  <td>{billing_name}</td>
                  <td>{if is_order_paid}Yes{if:else}No{/if}</td>
                  <td>{order_total}</td>
                  <td>{shipping_address1}</td>
                  <td>{shipping_address2}</td>
                  <td>{shipping_address3}</td>
                  <td>{billing_phone}</td>
                  <td>{order_email}</td>
                  {items}
                      {if sku == "FAM-SM" OR sku == "FAM-4-S"}
                        {modifiers limit="1"}
                            <td>{modifier_value}</td>
                        {/modifiers}
                        <td>N/A</td>
                      {if:else}
                        {modifiers}
                            <td>{modifier_value}</td>
                         {/modifiers}
                      {/if}
                      {if sku == "FAM-4-S"}
                        <td>{order_custom3}</td>
                        <td>{order_custom4}</td>
                        <td>{order_custom5}</td>
                      {if:else}
                          <td>N/A</td>
                          <td>N/A</td>
                          <td>N/A</td>
                      {/if}
               {/items}

                </tr>
            {/exp:query}
```

Comment: If you want to pull more then just the order_id you need to tell the query to select it something along the lines of `{exp:query sql="SELECT * FROM exp_store_orders ORDER BY order_date DESC LIMIT 2000"}` would allow you to use all of the table's column names in your templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have store installed on my sandbox to text with right this second, but worst case you could always pull this information via the exp:query module

It'd go something like

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT order_id FROM exp_store_orders ORDER BY order_date DESC LIMIT 2000"}
    {order_id}
{/exp:query}
```

You can ORDER BY whatever works, probably by order_id itself and have a list of the last 2000 orders

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm able to get the order_id but not the rest of the information I'm looking for. I've updated my post above with the full code I'm trying to use.